# Limit User Control of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I've got a game where you create words using letters in a letter bank. Every time a letter is typed, I want the letter icon to disappear, and reappear when it is erased. I have most of the functionality done already, but there are a few bugs I cannot fix. Right now I am using a `KeyListener` and filtering input/taking action based on key events. However, complications arise when multiple keys are pressed at the same time.

The input filtering isn't my main problem, it's putting the letters back in the bank when they are erased. Is there a way to remove the caret entirely and only allow users to add input to / backspace from the end of the `JTextField`? Also, any tips about handling button mashing correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Note: If you've ever played Super Text Twist, that's basically the type of guessing method that I'm going for.

Comment: Are you attached to the way you are doing it now? I would suggest putting a listener on the JTextField, and then everytime it changes, check all the text in there against the available letters, your program will do alot more work, but it should still be able to keep up no problem. This will not stop the user from typing in letters that are not included though...

Comment: Make the JTextField non-editable via setEditable(false) and then use your KeyListener (or key bindings) to add or remove characters.

Comment: @dann.dev that seems very inefficient, even if the program could keep up. I'd rather check on a per-key level than end up re-checking multiple letters every time the input changes.

Comment: @dann.dev: idea can work, especially with a DocumentFilter that checks input *before* it is posted to the text component, effectively preventing the user from adding or removing the wrong data.

Comment: Got it to work with a combination of KeyListeners and a non-editable JTextFIeld, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Max inefficient, yes, but I like it because you don't have to rely on your state being what you expect it to be. As you said, with mashing etc some unexpected things can happen with keyboard input. Glad it's working though!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels interesting, haven't come across class before but it looks immensly useful! Will check it out next time I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `PlainDocument` (used in `JTextField`) and override insertString() and remove() methods. The yoou can check what's inserted or removed and adapt your interface.

Or (may be even better) use the `DocumentFilter` as suggested `Hovercraft Full Of Eels`